# How to replicate Tab spacing in latex?

Tags: spacing

What I mean by Tab spacing is when you put tab spacing "→" (like in some WYSIWYG editor) so the space is flexible but also align text into some kind of measurement. I already know that I can replicate such thing with tabular environment but that's not quite practical since I need to call it repeatedly in many places scattered within document and I'd like to put that into a convenient macros. Is it possible to do such thing in LaTeX? Below is shown my replication in InDesign, tab space shown as "»".

[image: pic]

Comment: Can you state clearly (1) what you'd like to type, in your input document, and (2) what you'd like the output to look like, exactly?

Comment: It's hard to put on words since I'm not a native.

What I want to achieve is the exact same as the picture depicts. In my document, I'm going to use a single line of three phrases separated by space in a fixed alignment(?). It's different from `\hfill{x}` or any of that kind which produces rather fixed space than flexible space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While perhaps not ideal for use throughout the document, the built in `tabbing` environment is something I often use for this purpose. Within the environment you can use `\=` to set a tab stop and then on another line you can move through the tab stops using `\>`. This allows you to create what you're looking for, but you have to manually set the tab stops in your first line.

Short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
    Column One \hspace{1em} \= Column Two \hspace{1em} \= Etc. \\
    Item 1 \> Item 2 \> Item 3
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabbing example]

Comment: I don't know `tabbing` before, this is nearly perfect. Although I cannot use it without declaring the environment before. But thanks.